# Не получается правильно обработать событие mouseover и mouseout с использованием setTimeout, clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, dom

У меня есть код, который запускает (`mouseover`) видео при наведении курсора мыши и останавливает (`mouseout`) при отведении курсора мыши.

Вопрос в том, что мне нужно, чтобы **видео при наведении курсора мыши срабатывало не сразу, а по истечении 2 секунд после наведения**. Код, который я привожу ниже делает как нужно, но если я наведу курсор и сразу его уберу (раньше чем пройдёт 2 секунды), видео всё равно запуститься, а не должно.

Нигде нет нужной мне информации, все приводят вот такой вариант, но он меня в корне не устраивает:

```html
<button onclick="myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)">Запуск</button>
<button onclick="clearTimeout(myVar)">Остановить</button>
```

Мне необходимо использовать `event.target`, т.к. видео будет на странице не одно.

Мой код:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video')

let time = (e) => {
    return setTimeout(() => handlstart(e), 2000);
} 

const handlstart = (e) => {
    e.target.play()
}

const handlstop = (e) => {
    e.target.pause()
}

const handlend = (e) => {
    e.target.load()
    e.target.play();
}

const handlrestart = (e) => {
    e.target.load();
}

video.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => setTimeout(() => handlstart(e), 2000))
video.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => time(e))
video.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    window.clearTimeout(time(e));
    handlstop(e);
})
video.addEventListener('ended', handlend)
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <video muted src="https://tekeye.uk/html/images/Joren_Falls_Izu_Jap.mp4"></video>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понял зачем вы повесили два обработчика на `mouseover`, которые делают одно и тоже действие, но ладно, проблема тут не в этом.

Функция `setTimeout` возвращает `id` таймера, функция `clearTimeout` принимает этот самый `id` и останавливает таймер именно тот у которого переданный `id`. В вашем случае вы ни в первом обработчике `mouseover` не сохраняете возвращенный `id`, ни во втором.

А в `mouseout` вы вызвав свою функцию `timer`, создаете еще один таймер и уже `id` нового (третьего) созданного таймера, вы передаете в `clearTimeout`, который сразу же его и очищает.

Чтобы реализовать то, что вам нужно. Вам нужно хранить `id` созданных таймеров.

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');
// Объект в котором будут храниться id таймеров 
// Ключ для примера используется id у тега video
// Значение соответственно - сам id
let timerIds = {};

// Функция обработчик наведения на тег
const handleMouseOver = (e) => {
  // Создаем таймер при помощи setTimeout
  // и сохраняем полученный id в timerIds
  // по id тега
  timerIds[e.target.id] = setTimeout(() => {
    // Внутри обработчика через 2000 миллисекунд (2 секунды)
    // запускаем видео
    e.target.play();
    // и удаляем id из объекта, опять же по id тега
    delete timerIds[e.target.id];
  }, 2000);
}

// Функция обработчик выход за пределы тега курсором
const handleMouseOut = (e) => {
  // Останавливаем таймер по id тега
  clearTimeout(timerIds[e.target.id]);
  // Удаляем id таймера
  delete timerIds[e.target.id];
  // Ставим видео на паузу
  e.target.pause();
}

// Функция обработчик остановки видео, но тут все понятно
const handleVideoEnded = (e) => {
  e.target.load();
  e.target.play();
}

video.addEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseOver);
video.addEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseOut);
video.addEventListener('ended', handleVideoEnded);
```

```html
<video muted id="first_player" src="https://tekeye.uk/html/images/Joren_Falls_Izu_Jap.mp4"></video>
```

P.s. в примере кстати, можно заметить, что используется одна переменная в которую и сохраняется `id` таймера.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, я понял свои ошибки!